# How does the keyboard input get into the terminal?

Tags: keyboard, operating-system, hardware, ascii

Can someone describe the way how keyboard input gets on the Computer Screen?! What kind of software/hardware is involved?

my question is what happens roughly or exactly when i press a key on my keyboard? what kind of software hardware is involved. does the 8 bit ascii gets directly to the cpu? and how does it get onto the screen with the help of the OS e.g. Linux?

Comment: my question is what happens roughly or exactly when i press a key on my keyboard? what kind of software hardware is involved. does the 8 bit ascii gets directly to the cpu? and how does it get onto the screen with the help of the OS e.g. Linux?

Comment: please edit those remarks into your question.

Comment: Linus Åkesson has written up an article on the TTY system, which is part of the answer to a very big question. The total answer is OS-dependent; this partial answer is for unix-derivatives. It's at https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you check out this website called HowStuffWorks on [How Computer Keyboards Work](http://www.howstuffworks.com/keyboard.htm). It states in sum:

> As you type, the processor in the keyboard analyzes the key matrix and
>   determines what characters to send to the computer. It maintains these
>   characters in its memory buffer and then sends the data.

and

> Many keyboards connect to the computer through a cable with a PS/2 or
>   USB (Universal Serial Bus) connector. Laptops use internal connectors.

and finally

> Whether it's through a cable or wireless, the signal from the keyboard
>   is monitored by the computer's keyboard controller. This is an
>   integrated circuit (IC) that processes all of the data that comes from
>   the keyboard and forwards it to the operating system. When the
>   operating system (OS) is notified that there is data from the
>   keyboard, it checks to see if the keyboard data is a system level
>   command. A good example of this is Ctrl-Alt-Delete on a Windows
>   computer, which reboots the system. Then, the OS passes the keyboard
>   data on to the current application.

The data is sent via cable or wireless also (IR or other wireless technology).

Wikipedia also has a nice [writeup on keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard#Technology),

> Computer keyboards include control circuitry to convert key presses
>   into key codes that the computer's electronics can understand. The key
>   switches are connected via the printed circuit board in an electrical
>   X-Y matrix where a voltage is provided sequentially to the Y lines
>   and, when a key is depressed, detected sequentially by scanning the X
>   lines.